# stop aligning controls in center of border component

Tags: c#, wpf, controls, border

How can I make stop things from aligning center inside a Border control?

I tried to modify the properties, but couldn't find the right one and everything I add to the Border Control is aligned centerly...

how to stop it?

thanks,
Joe

Answer (score 3, accepted):

set alignment properties on the border's child like this:

```
<Border BorderBrush="Black" 
        BorderThickness="1" 
        Height="100" 
        Width="100">

    <Button Content="Button" 
            Width="50" 
            Height="50" 
            HorizontalAlignment="Right" 
            VerticalAlignment="Bottom"/>

</Border>
```

Comment: what if I want to manually align the control inside the border?

Comment: @Jonathan - what do you mean?  Robert's answer shows how to align a control to the Right.  If you need other controls inside the Border, you can use any container control (StackPanel, Grid, etc.).

Comment: @Jonathan - if you want to control the placement within the Border, use the Margin to place it where you need to.